# User authentication with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am writing a web application using PHP. I want to use the MVC pattern for this, and decided to go with [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). My application will have some pages which will require authentication, and some pages won't. I want to design this in a very generic way, so that there should be no code duplication. Can any one point to some good "design/class structure" for this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write a custom library that you can autoload in your code igniter app on every page view. It should have functions that:

- Authenticate the user ie. check if a user is logged in or not
- Log you in ie. set a session variable or something
- Log you out

Then in your controller classes you can do a call to the authentication function in the constructor then depending on the outcome continue as normal or redirect them to a login screen with an access denied message.

Do a search on the code igniter wiki for 'authentication' and there are a number of results that may help: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/

Comment: i've always put the log in / log out functions (as well as a few others) into an "auth" controller. In any individual controller i can check if the user's logged in by seeing if $this->session->userdata('uid') is set. Is that bad practice?

Comment: i agree, it's really easy to create your own auth.

Answer (score 10):

"Ion Auth" is lean, well-programmed, somewhat widely used and is actively maintained.

http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Answer (score 3):

If by "some pages" you mean some controllers (the gateway to your views), then you may want to investigate controller inheritance. Extend the default CodeIgniter controller with your own and put an authentication check in the constructor (check the session for a logged in flag or something and if not logged in then redirect to login page). Then, all controllers that require authentication will need to extend your new parent controller. That's it.

Head on over to the CodeIgniter forums and search for some different ways to extend the controller. Here is one http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/89768/#452890

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the same thing recently, and I found a CodeIgniter fork called [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) that includes a nice [authentication module](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/addons/auth). If you are set on CI, maybe adapting Kohana's auth module backwards to CI would save you some time? If you have just started out on your project and PHP5 is OK to use, consider switching over; they are very similar frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use CL_AUTH library for CI. I've used it and it works good. You can find it here http://www.jasonashdown.co.uk/cl_auth_doc/

Answer (score 0):

Visit [GitHub](https://github.com/) and search for Codeigniter Auth or Authentication, or check the [CodeIgniter Wiki](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Contributions#libraries),  you'll find many libraries with different features.. explore them and choose the one you need! But be careful, many are for CI 2, and you have to [ucfirst the classes](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names) to use with CI 3, otherwise they don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexi auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/) a modified version of the popular [Ion Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) library. It's more advanced and do all the job out-of-the-box.

> flexi auth is a free open source user authentication/login library for use with the CodeIgniter 2.0+ framework.

I know it's too late but I hope someone else will find it helpful. **Cheers!**

Comment: flexi_auth is updated 7 years ago while ion_auth is still under active development. I would recommend ion_auth ;)