# Block access to functions in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, permissions

I'm developing a application in Code Igniter and a problem come by:

I have several functions that access the database, that are routed like this:

controller/function/variable
employess/deleteEmployee/4

So, anyone that put this on the url gonna delete the employee.

How can I manage to allow only a logged admin user to access this functions?
Is there a simple and well accepted way?
I must check every time if there is a user logged in and this user have the permission?

Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter authentication + user privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977707/codeigniter-authentication-user-privileges)

Comment: Add a check in your controller __construct method. It will check for every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the URL for the reference...

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Here is the simple example

```
Copy this piece of code as checksession.php and save it in /application/hooks
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class Checksession
        {
            private $CI;

            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->CI =&get_instance();
            }

            public function index()
            {
                if($this->CI->router->fetch_class() != "login"){
                    // session check logic here...change this accordingly
                    if($this->CI->session->userdata['userid'] == '' ){
                        redirect('login');
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Copy this code in /application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class' => 'checksession',
                                'function' => 'index',
                                'filename' => 'checksession.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Enable hooks in /application/config/config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Hope this helps.
Good Luck and Happy Coding

Comment: Thx for the help, but this solves only half of my problem. 
I have 3 types (roles) of users on my application: admin, managers and employees.

- Admin can do everything
- Managers can do a lot
- Employees are very restricted.

So I must set the permission of every Constructor according to the role in the session.
But I think that I can do it from here, creating an array in every method specifying the roles permitted, and them checking in this hook you've posted. Right?

Thx in advance.