# User Authentication/Authorisation in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, authentication, openid

I am building a social platform in Codeigniter..And i wish to implement a Social Login Option like StackOverflow(which uses OpenId) where user can select Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter or Google to login into my site..
I know of few PHP libraries like OpenId, A3M for CI..

My query is will A3M detect a user loggin in via Linked In is already a signed-up user who initially used FB and map both the Ids with the same user instead of generating new User.

Is there a better suggested alternative to A3M for my requiremnets

Comment: possible duplicate of [User authentication with CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457497/user-authentication-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Phil Sturgeon's 'Codeigniter OAuth'.

> An implementation of the OAuth protocol with drivers to work with
>   different providers such as Twitter, Google, etc.

OAuth: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth

and

OAuth 2.0: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2

Both, and others are also available at http://getsparks.org/packages/summary