# Authentication engine for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

What is the best user authentication engine(system/framework) for the CodeIgniter framework in PHP? I'm new to PHP, but have huge java skills. In java I use shiro or spring security, but what should I use in PHP (especially for CodeIgniter)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [User authentication with CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457497/user-authentication-with-codeigniter)

Comment: check out my library https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter

Answer (score 3):

There are a multitude of good auth libraries available for CodeIgniter. Take a look [here](http://blog.pisyek.com/2011/11/5-best-authentication-libraries-for-codeigniter/) for a good article on a few of them. In personal experience, I rolled my own authentication which wasn't too difficult, if you have the time and wish to do so.

Also take note that EllisLab is [no longer supporting CodeIgniter.](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/ellislab-seeking-new-owner-for-codeigniter) If this is a new project that you are looking to maintain for the foreseeable future, I might suggest taking a look at [Laravel.](http://laravel.com/) It has become increasingly popular, is very robust, has a great community, and has no shortage of information and tutorials around the web to learn from.

Comment: Re: EllisLab no longer supporting CodeIgniter.  It appears that they are still releasing updates and security patches.  However I'm not a member of their community so I don't know the full extent and planned lifetime for that.

Answer (score 2):

For Authentication and codeigniter, Ion Auth is very popular, easy to use, and is actively maintained.

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Codeigniter is an extremely popular framework that also runs on older php 5.2 servers. EllisLab is not abandoning codeigniter - quite the opposite they are inviting potential relationship material to the party. i would not be surprised if apple ended up buying it, would make a lot of sense since they use it internally.